# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table column which is designed as below

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[client_Presence]
(  
    [ClientID] [varchar](15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Z923FormPath] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now, I'm trying to into update the above table like below.

```
UPDATE  client_Presence
    SET Z923FormPath    =   'c:\windows\Z923Form.pdf'
    FROM    Client_Presence
    WHERE   ClientID    =   '12345'
```

I was able update Null value, '' value, getdate(), Why I'm not able to update with string value.

with the above operation I'm receiving the below error, could you please help on it?

```
Procedure: Tr_client_Presence (Line: 19)
Line 19: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: There is a trigger called `Tr_client_Presence` on table firing on update. Please check it. Error is happening in there (Line 19).

Comment: Also, you have tagged question both `mysql` and `sql-server-2008`. It can only be one of those (And it's SQL Server I guess based on error messages and syntax)

Comment: Answer is, Column sequence is not matching between client_presence and client_presence_log tables, DBA has to correct it.

Comment: Column sequence is not something that should be relevant. It's poor query design if it is. I guess you have something like `INSERT INTO log_table SELECT * FROM table`. You should change trigger to include column names in both `INSERT` and `SELECT` part. Should be something like `INSERT INTO log_table (colA, colB) SELECT colA, colB FROM table`

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to update the value to getDate() and updating to a non-empty string gives you an error it looks like you've incorrectly set the column's data type to a date.  Are you sure the code snippets posted are correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure about it. I checked it 1000-times.